# iOS send data to PHP

Tags: php, ios, objective-c

I'm having problem sending information to the PHP file at my server.
I need some favor , i give up and almost can give up with this problems ahead.

IBAction:-

```
- (IBAction)reg:(id)sender {
    NSInteger success = 0;
    @try {
        NSString *rawStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"username=%@",self.txtEmail.text];
        NSData *data = [rawStr dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://something.com/register.php"];
        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

        [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
        [request setHTTPBody:data];

        NSURLResponse *response;
        NSError *err;
        NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&err];
        NSLog(@"responseData: %@", responseData);
    }
    @catch (NSException * e) {
        NSLog(@"Exception: %@", e);
        [self alertStatus:@"Sign in Failed." :@"Error!" :0];
    }
    if (success) {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"login_success" sender:self];
    }
}
```

This sends to my PHP file in my server

```
<?php
    $email      =   $_GET['username'];
    $email2      =   $_POST['username'];
    mail('thepridelagoon@gmail.com','testing' , $email,$email2);
?>
```

I tried to test these two functions to send to my email but the email was empty for a reason.
Did I went wrong??
Please help me out ty.

Comment: why are you mixing get and post? And have you done **ANY** basic debugging yourself? e.g. `var_dump($_GET, $_POST)` to see if your app is actually sending anything in the first place?

Comment: As @MarcB says, try `var_dump($_GET)` and `var_dump($_POST)` to see what the output is. Alså, I see you are sending the data as POST, so my guess is that `$_POST['username']` is correct.

Comment: @ronnyandre , i did both cause the Xcode is just mailing but empty value , I'm going to try Marc B suggestion.

Comment: @MarcB, I did like this but it return nothing not even an email

<?php
    $email      =   var_dump($_GET['username’]);
    $email2      =   var_dump($_POST['username’]);
?>

Comment: vardump does debug output. And don't dump just the 'username' stuff. dump ALL of _GET and _POST, just like I said. if you still get nothing, then it's your ios code that's not sending anything.

Comment: @MarcB , It is my IOS code doing the problem . I tried to send email my way of debug but it return empty even it's string. It's the IOS code but when i google around . Most of them use nSurl , is it wrong in my IOS code??

Comment: @MarcB , yeah it's confirm the IOS code . I dump all the vardump and still get empty value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct answer is :

```
NSString *rawStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"username=%@",self.txtEmail.text];
        NSData *data = [rawStr dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://something.com/register.php"];
        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

        [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
        [request setHTTPBody:data];

        NSURLResponse *response;
        NSError *err;
        NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&err];
        NSLog(@"responseData: %@", responseData);
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey I tried running this code on my server as well and it didn't do anything for me. However this snippet seemed to do the trick.

```
    NSURL *postURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://something.com/register.php"];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:postURL];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"content-type"];

    NSString *postString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"username=%@", username.text];
    [request setHTTPBody:[postString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [request setValue:postString forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Not working . Even it passes information but empty value.
Basically something is wrong with the iOS code itself.
It even sent email to test but empty value.
When i try to do manually by www.something.com/register.php?username=test.
it showed test in my email basically the PHP has no issue just the iOS code.

Comment: are you getting any errors in your code? Also this might be dumb question but is your button connected to your UI?

Comment: There's no error , it's running the PHP line fine but there's no value . The Button is connected to the UI , i double checked else the PHP won't send the mail to my messenger.

Comment: Ok. Is there any other information that you can provide me with because I know that the code from above works.

Comment: @RockPaperScissors Is your content-length header correct?  Shouldn't the value be the length of postString?

Comment: @Paulw11 I don't think so. `[request setValue:postString forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];` has always worked for me.

Comment: Maybe the server is accepting it, but it is wrong. Content-length should be a number, not the post string

Comment: I need to enter string to pass but it returns empty string.

Comment: Ok log the string that you want to pass and see if it is the actual value which you want to pass. If not your UiTextField may not be connected.